# Using apollo subscribeToMore with different results for subscription

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

GET_USERS returns `users: []string`

```
export const GET_USERS= gql`
    query AllUsers{
        users
    }
`;
```

GET_USERS_SUBSCRIPTION returns `user: string`

```
export const GET_USERS_SUBSCRIPTION= gql`
    subscription AllUsersUpdater{
        user
    }
`;
```

It seems like apollo expects the subscribeToMore to be of the exact same result type. I know I can update the result to also be `[]string`, but that seems so unnecessary for what I want to do.

```
   const { subscribeToMore } = useAllUsersQuery({});
    useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToMore({
                document: GET_USERS_SUBSCRIPTION,
                updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                    if (!subscriptionData.data) {
                        return prev;
                    }
                    const user= subscriptionData.data.user;
                    if (prev.users.find((u) => u === user)) {
                        return prev;
                    }
                    return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                        users: [user, ...prev.users],
                    });
                },
            });
     }, []);
```

Is there any way to use `subscribeToMore` with a different subscription type?

Also, is `subscribeToMore` the best way to handle this? Could I just bundle the two and just have the subscription return past results prior to returning new ones?

Answer (score 0):

The `subscribeToMore` as defined here https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/a3aefcb310ea1451ee494077cbde98171169d8d0/src/core/ObservableQuery.ts#L502-L505 used the `TSubscriptionData = TData` type parameter to set the expected type which defaults to `TData`.
You need to specify the parameter to override the default.

In your specific example this would look something like this

```
   const { subscribeToMore } = useAllUsersQuery({});
    useEffect(() => {
    subscribeToMore<{user: string}>({
                document: GET_USERS_SUBSCRIPTION,
                updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                    if (!subscriptionData.data) {
                        return prev;
                    }
                    const user= subscriptionData.data.user;
                    if (prev.users.find((u) => u === user)) {
                        return prev;
                    }
                    return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                        users: [user, ...prev.users],
                    });
                },
            });
     }, []);
```